# React Native setState issue using an Object with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

I am having trouble with the setState of objects.
My interface definition is as follows;

```
export interface IProjectData {
  Id?: string,
  Description?: string,
  ProjectState?: string,
}
```

I access the parameter I sent with RootStackParamList as follows.

```
function ProjectScreen({ route, navigation }: ProjectProps) {
  const [project, setProject] = useState<IProjeData>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const sProject = JSON.stringify(route.params.project)
    let myProject: IProjeData = JSON.parse(sProject)
    console.log('myProject: ')
    console.log(myProject)
    setProject(myProject)
    console.log('Project: ')
    console.log(project)
  }, [])

  return (
    ...
    ...
  )}
```

Consol output is as follows. Where am I going wrong? Why can't I assign a value to project?

```
myProject: 
{Id: "bd7acbea", Description"My Test Project", ProjectState"25/25"}
Project: 
null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setProject` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated `project` value right immediately after `setProject`.

You should use `useEffect` with adding a `project` dependency to get an updated `project` value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(project)
}, [ project ])
```